Getting ModuleNotFoundError on a Windows machine
I have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Blank-Grabber-main\Blank-Grabber-main\Blank Grabber\env\Scripts\process.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyaes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaes'

'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command
or external command, an executable program or a command file.

I tried pip install setuptools ; pip install pyaes ; pip uninstall pyaes pip install pyaes

I tried pip install pyaes And what happened when you tried that?  Did the installation seem to work?

The error indicates that pyinstaller needs to be able to be run without a full path. Thus you need to amend your Windows path so that it contains the binaries directory containing this command.
